# Stop Active Directory Users installing updates

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-update

We have multiple PCs running Windows 8 for testing on an AD.

However, Windows update keeps pushing the Windows 8.1, but we need the PCs to strictly be on 8.

How could I stop AD users from installing updates and only allow admins to do so?

We run windows server 2012.

I'm quite new to this, so I don't know all the techy stuff regarding it.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry my answer, will stop the windows 8.1 update but allow other updates. Not sure if the 8.1 was just an example or did you want no updates at all?

Comment: the 8.1 is one of the issues, but mainly to stop all updates and only allow admins to decide if they want the updates to go ahead and install them

Comment: Strangely enough, by design all users can install updates. You can control the notification of the update so they won't get told about it, but if they go looking for windows updates they will be able to install them. The other option is a WSUS server, this will stop the update being delivered to the computer so there will be no updates there to be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you implement a WSUS server and use group policy to point to the WSUS server for updates and then only approve the updates you require?

That would at least give you central Control of what updates are installed on the workstations.

Comment: Would i have to setup group policy to disallow windows updates?

Comment: WSUS is the ideal way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can control the 8.1 update in a couple of ways

In group policy configure the following policy and set it to enabled

```
Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Store -> Turn off the offer to update to the latest version of Windows
```

Or

Change the following registry key 'DisableOSUpgrade' to 1 located in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsStore
```

Full guide [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-update-to-windows-8-1-for-free-notification-in-windows-8-store/)

Answer (score 1):

Create a container (OU). Place the machines into that OU. Set the following group policy.

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Store

I think from memory, the setting is Turn off automatic download of updates on windows 8 machines